# Bootstrap 5 Cards need to be all same height using SwiperJS Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I am not a CSS expert. I want all of the cards in a swiperjs slider to have the same height, no matter what the content is in the card. At the moment, the content of some of the cards is a different height. My code looks like this image and my sample code is below. How do I make my cards in swiperjs all have the same height?

[image: Image of the problem]

Here is the sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="portfolio" class="mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mb-4">
                    <h2>Projects I have completed for my clients</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="swiper myClients animate__animated animate__pulse">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="card mb-5">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Tuffwraps Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Tuffwraps</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Built a script that:<br />
                                            1) Scans the products for tags in your Shopify cart <br />
                                            2) If 3 products contain a same tag, the customer will be awarded 20% off <br />
                                            3) Similarly, 4 will get them 25% off, and 5 or more will get them 30% off.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify Plus</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="card mb-5">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Travelbass Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Travelbass</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Added a cart slider, made it so the page doesn't refresh in case a new item is added into a cart, while updating information about the quantity and price of products.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="card mb-5">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CEA Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">CEA</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Tailored the responsive view for mobile devices.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="card mb-5">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="TCL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">THE CLOATHING LOUNGE</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Built a new design look</p>
                                        <a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="card mb-5">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Creative Lighters</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Fixed a broken monthly subscription for a mystery box product</p>
                                        <a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var myClients = new Swiper(".myClients", {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                autoHeight: true,
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 5000,
                },
                loop: true,
                pagination: {
                    el: ".swiper-pagination",
                    clickable: true,
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                    draggable: true,
                },
                breakpoints: {
                    "@0.00": {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                    },
                    "@1.00": {
                        slidesPerView: 2,
                        spaceBetween: 30,
                    },
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank PeterJames because of your answer I will able to figure out how can I make it all same height and here is mine solution to this problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    <style>
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="portfolio" class="mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mb-4">
                    <h2>Projects I have completed for my clients</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="swiper myClients animate__animated animate__pulse">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper h-auto">
                            <div class="swiper-slide mb-5 h-auto">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Tuffwraps Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Tuffwraps</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Built a script that:<br />
                                            1) Scans the products for tags in your Shopify cart <br />
                                            2) If 3 products contain a same tag, the customer will be awarded 20% off <br />
                                            3) Similarly, 4 will get them 25% off, and 5 or more will get them 30% off.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify Plus</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide mb-5 h-auto">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Travelbass Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Travelbass</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Added a cart slider, made it so the page doesn't refresh in case a new item is added into a cart, while updating information about the quantity and price of products.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide mb-5 h-auto">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CEA Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">CEA</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">
                                            Tailored the responsive view for mobile devices.
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide mb-5 h-auto">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="TCL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">THE CLOATHING LOUNGE</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Built a new design look</p>
                                        <a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide mb-5 h-auto">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg">
                                        <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Creative Lighters</a></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Fixed a broken monthly subscription for a mystery box product</p>
                                        <a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var myClients = new Swiper(".myClients", {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                setWrapperSize: true,
                roundLengths: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 5000,
                },
                loop: true,
                pagination: {
                    el: ".swiper-pagination",
                    clickable: true,
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
                    draggable: true,
                },
                breakpoints: {
                    "@0.00": {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                    },
                    "@1.00": {
                        slidesPerView: 2,
                        spaceBetween: 30,
                    },
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `height: auto;` to `.swiper-slide` in the CSS.

Set `autoHeight:false` as a slider object parameter. The [**sliderjs** docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters) say that if `autoHeight` is set to `true` then the slider wrapper will adapt its height to the height of the currently active slide -- which is not what you want.

Set `vh-100` on each `card`. Other `vh` values may or may not work. I have not tested them properly, but I don't think they work too well.

Finally, the text content was overflowing, so set the font size for the `card` class to something smaller. However, changing the font size will depend on your particular layout.

```css
.swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <style>
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="portfolio" class="mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mb-4">
          <h2>Projects I have completed for my clients</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
          <div class="swiper myClients animate__animated animate__pulse">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card vh-100 mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Tuffwraps Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Tuffwraps</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Built a script that:<br /> 1) Scans the products for tags in your Shopify cart <br /> 2) If 3 products contain a same tag, the customer will be awarded 20% off <br /> 3) Similarly, 4 will get them 25% off, and 5 or more will get
                      them 30% off.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify Plus</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card vh-100 mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Travelbass Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Travelbass</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Added a cart slider, made it so the page doesn't refresh in case a new item is added into a cart, while updating information about the quantity and price of products.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card vh-100 mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CEA Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">CEA</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Tailored the responsive view for mobile devices.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card vh-100 mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="TCL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">THE CLOATHING LOUNGE</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Built a new design look</p>
                    <a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card vh-100 mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Creative Lighters</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Fixed a broken monthly subscription for a mystery box product</p>
                    <a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var myClients = new Swiper(".myClients", {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000,
        },
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
        scrollbar: {
          el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
          draggable: true,
        },
        breakpoints: {
          "@0.00": {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          "@1.00": {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure the problem falls with `.card-body`. You have a varying amount of content for each `.card-body` which is determining the `height` of each `.card`.

Set a `height` on `.card-body` and use `overflow-y: scroll;` so that the `.cards` with the most content have a scrollbar. I added a custom scrollbar that is always visibile to demonstrate.

```css
.card-body {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}



.card-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.card-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--bs-primary);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <style>
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="portfolio" class="mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mb-4">
          <h2>Projects I have completed for my clients</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 justify-content-center">
          <div class="swiper myClients animate__animated animate__pulse">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tuff.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Tuffwraps Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Tuffwraps</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Built a script that:<br /> 1) Scans the products for tags in your Shopify cart <br /> 2) If 3 products contain a same tag, the customer will be awarded 20% off <br /> 3) Similarly, 4 will get them 25% off, and 5 or more will get
                      them 30% off.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://uk.tuffwraps.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify Plus</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/travelbass.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Travelbass Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Travelbass</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Added a cart slider, made it so the page doesn't refresh in case a new item is added into a cart, while updating information about the quantity and price of products.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://travelbass.myshopify.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cea.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CEA Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">CEA</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Tailored the responsive view for mobile devices.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://www.shop-cea.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/tcl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="TCL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">THE CLOATHING LOUNGE</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Built a new design look</p>
                    <a href="https://www.the-clothinglounge.com/" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="card mb-5">
                  <a data-fslightbox href="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg">
                    <img src="https://stefan-momcilovic.com/assets/images/cl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="CL Image" class="swiper-lazy">
                  </a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Creative Lighters</a></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Fixed a broken monthly subscription for a mystery box product</p>
                    <a href="https://creativelighters.com/products/the-mystery-subscription" class="text-primary" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Shopify</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var myClients = new Swiper(".myClients", {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoHeight: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000,
        },
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
        scrollbar: {
          el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
          draggable: true,
        },
        breakpoints: {
          "@0.00": {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          "@1.00": {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```